# Qt - steps to using QOpenGLWidget to display images

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm trying to use a QOpenGLWidget to show some images instead of using QLabel. But I'm a bit confused about how to do this.

To make the widget get the job done, I know I need to reimplement the `initializeGL()` method and `paintGL()` method.

To get the texture of an image, what I used is `SOIL_load_image()`. Why is `unsigned char* img_data` over `unsigned char* img_data[3]`? I think each pixel of an image has 3 values(**RGB**).

After getting the texture, I have no idea what I should do and where should I do them in `initializeGL()` or `paintGL()`. Can anyone tell the steps?

```
void MyOpenGLWidget::loadTexture(const char* file_path)
{
    *image = cv::imread(file_path, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    width = image->rows;
    height = image->cols;
    int channels = image->channels();
    img_data = SOIL_load_image(file_path, &width, &height, &channels, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation already? See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is unsigned char* img_data over unsigned char* img_data[3]

`unsigned char*` is a pointer to a buffer (of arbitrary length) of data. `unsigned char* …[3]` is an array of 3 pointers to buffers of data. You have only one buffer, not 3.

For some reason you're using both OpenCV and then SOIL to read the same image two times. Why?

Once you've loaded the image, to display it with OpenGL you have to

1. Create a texture object (glGenTextures, glBindTexture, glTexImage)
2. Create some geometry to draw it (usually a quad, or a viewport filling triangle), by filling a vertex buffer object (glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData) and associating the data in the buffer with vertex attributes of a vertex array object (glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray, glEnableVertexArrayAttrib, glVertexAttribPointer)
3. Create a shader program, consisting of a vertex shader that places the geometry and paramtizes the fragment shader, which actually samples from the texture. (glCreateShader, glShaderSource, glCreateProgram, glLinkProgram)

Then to draw

1. select the shader program (glUseProgram)
2. set parameters (glUniform)
3. draw (glDrawArrays)

Comment: yes you're right. but I'm not sure if I need to deal with RGB values like do I need to separate the img_data to new_img_data[0], new_img_data[1] and new_im_data[2]. But it seems I don't need to do that

Comment: @Jinx: There's not need to create a planar (images separated into individual red, green and blue monochrome layers) image. You're supposed to pass the raw data buffer to OpenGL and tell OpenGL in what format the data arrives.